# how to use transaction of mysql in "save_model" and "delete_model" of django admin

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, admin

class DispatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
def delete_model(self, request, obj):
    a.delete()
    b.delete()

def save_model(self,request,obj,form,change):
    x.save()
    y.save()
```

## __*_*__*_*__*How can I****_*__*_*____**

how can I make the operation to the mysql database as
a atomic operation by using the transaction?
what should be "import",and if the action is failed,
how to rollback?(notes:since I use django admin,there is no extra views.py)