# display different list_display depends on user

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model include some columns: A,B,C.When the logger is superuser,the list_display will includes all the columns(A,B,C),otherwise,other user can only see part of the columns,for example:B and C.Most of the related answer is user get_form(...),but this is alter the 'exclude','fields' and 'fieldsets',I want alter the list_dispaly.

Comment: You need to be clearer in your question? It sounds like you might want to overwrite the view of the `AdminModel` to conditionally add fields to your `list_display` based on current user permissions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would use the `changelist_view` method to edit `list_display`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('A', 'B', 'C',)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_display = ('B', 'C',)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003442/how-to-use-transaction-of-mysql-in-save-model-and-delete-model-of-django-adm,it's a link of another question I encountered,hope you can solve.